# Is a secret key for encrypted authentication required?

Tags: encryption, forms-authentication

Do I have to have a secret key added to my login form for encrypted authentication since I have a 2048-bit Certificate? How secure is that with/without it?

Comment: Are you talking about an SSL certificate?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I hope so, because if not, Peter is doing something wrong.

Comment: @Joachim. Yes, I'm talking about SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you perform the encryption yourself. If you use SSL or a container such as CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax), then the secret key is generated by the framework. You do need some session secret key to encrypt data such as forms.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have an SSL and want to know how to build session secert key to encrypt data. Is there an example on how to do that? also do I need it for registration form or authentication form?

Comment: BTW, is Openwall demo6 a good example on that? [Openwall demo6](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords)

Comment: You *really* don't want to implement SSL or TLS, you should use a known good implementation, and that implementation will generate the session key - there is no need to implement anything yourself. If you only allow AES TLS-suites, your password should be safe during transit - or at least as safe as possible at the moment.

Comment: I would not use Openwall demo6 because it does not seem to claim compatability with either bcrypt or PBKDF2, which are the standards to adhere to at the moment. The page does seem to give some solid advice (although I cannot verify everything at this point in time) and possibly the code behind it is good as well. But not following any standard makes it hard to test and hard to port to other runtimes.

Comment: Thanks owlstead for the great info. now I'm totally confused. I mean that I was trying to create  a safe membership system to my site, and wanted to learn how to make that system secure enough so that no leaks or attack happen to clients' private info. any idea how to start or are there any resources on this. I have gathered some info on how to create the member systems, but not yet sure about how secure they are. please advise.

Comment: BTW, would Generating a gpg/pgp key using SSH do something?

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion about this on StackOverflow. I would suggest to look for SSL/TLS (for the transport security), bcrypt/PBKDF2 (for keeping the passwords safe in the database) and of course PHP. GPG and or SSH are not required to keep form data safe - after SSL/TLS it is most important to control access to the database (this does not have to involve server side encryption, although it is one possiblity).